# Gradle sync failed: Cause: assert pluginDirectory.exists()

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have the error I put in the title and below. The error occurs when you open Android Studio on folder /android. My project is a Flutter project. I created my project with the Android app [Max 2D Game](https://max2dgame.com/) on my Samsung Galaxy A10.

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: assert pluginDirectory.exists()
                            |               |
                            |               false               > 
                           \root\snap\flutter\common\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.15.1\android
```

I invite you to explore my project on [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/#https://github.com/AlexandroGonSan/firtplay_to_stackoverflow) or fork on [GitHub](https://github.com/AlexandroGonSan/firtplay_to_stackoverflow) and submit a pull request fixing this error.

Opening android studio in the android/app folder I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.2.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> assert pluginDirectory.exists()
         |               |
         |               false
         \root\snap\flutter\common\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.15.1\android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 121ms
```

Comment: seems like the pub cache doesn't contain that specific plugin. try running `flutter pub get` again and then rebuild application

Comment: this solved for me

Comment: Oh wonderful, we should post an answer in order to help others. Do you want me to do that ?

Comment: yes, you can do it, it was precisely thinking about helping other people that I commented.

Answer (score 19):

`assert pluginDirectory.exists()` is returning the error since your `pub cache` somehow got out of sync.

In such cases, use the command

```
flutter pub get
```

from your root folder in order to resync all your dependencies with the cache.

Comment: flutter put get. love this